# Aura Component Attribute Value

Tags: controller, aura, lookup, record, component

I would like to set a lookup id value for an Aura attribute, but it doesn't work unless i hardcode it.
Instead I need to retrieve it from the lookup on the current recordId.

How is this possible to do? From the controller? The value is store in a lookup Child__c on the recordId of the record page where i run the component.

```
<aura:attribute
        name="myFilters"
        type="Resource__c"
        default="[{'fieldName':'Parent__c', 'operator':'=', 'value': 'a557S000001UJE1QAO' }]"
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard coded value is what works for default values in aura attributes, for dynamic values - it has to be set in controller.

Kindly try

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId" controller="ControllerClass">
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
<aura:attribute
    name="myFilters"
    type="Resource__c"
    default="[{'fieldName':'Parent__c', 'operator':'=', 'value': '' }]"
/>
</aura:component>
```

```
    ({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    //'fetchRecordValues' be the apex method in ControllerClass that gets current recordId as input and returns the record with Child__c field value
    var action = component.get("c.fetchRecordValues");
    action.setParams({
            "recordId": component.get('v.recordId')
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
    //get the returned record and store in a variable, which can then be used to get value of 'Child__c' field
                var storeResponse = response.getReturnValue();
               // set current Child__c information on default value
               component.set("v.myFilters.value" , storeResponse.Child__c );
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

For reference, kindly have a look at this thread - https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005PbXQAU

Comment: Please don't leave link-only answers. They can be broken over time (hint: foreshadowing).

Comment: sure thanks sfdcfox, will edit accordingly!

Comment: i tried with         component.set("v.Child__r.Id" ,lookupId ); 
and then in the cmp : 


<aura:attribute
        name="myFilters"
        type="B25__Resource__c"
  default="[{'fieldName':'Parent__c', 'operator':'=', 'value': 'lookupId' }]"
    />

But it doesn't work